# Avoiding distinct background appearing behind plo label text

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic, labeling

I keep getting a light background behind my text when I use the `PlotLabels` option (see picture below).

[image: graphics]

```
DynamicModule[
    {Demand, Supply, G,  F, X1, Y1, Y2, e\`Graf, Slutinterval, CS, PS, SS, 
     Slutx, Sluty, G1, F1, X11, Y11, Y22, Graf1, Slutinterval1, 
     CS1, PS1, SS1, Slutx1, Sluty1},  
  Manipulate[
    G=Q/.Solve[Supply==Demand,Q][[1]];
    F=Block[{Q=G},Supply];
    CS=N[Integrate[Demand,{Q,0,G}]-(F*G)];
    PS=N[(F*G)-Integrate[Supply,{Q,0,G}]];
    SS=CS+PS;
    X1:=G/6;
    Y1:=((Block[{Q=0},Demand])-F)/2;
    Y2:=F-((F-(Block[{Q=0},Supply]))/2);
    Slutinterval:=G+G/100*30;
    Slutx=Q/.Solve[Demand==0,Q][[1]];
    Sluty=Block[{Q=0},Demand];

    G1=Quiet[NumberForm[AccountingForm[N[Q/.Solve[Supply==Demand,Q][[1]]]],{\[Infinity],2}]];
    F1=Quiet[NumberForm[AccountingForm[N[Block[{Q=G},Supply]]],{\[Infinity],2}]];
    CS1=Quiet[NumberForm[AccountingForm[N[Integrate[Demand,{Q,0,G}]-(F*G)]],{\[Infinity],2}]];
    PS1=Quiet[NumberForm[AccountingForm[N[(F*G)-Integrate[Supply,{Q,0,G}]]],{\[Infinity],2}]];
    SS1=Quiet[NumberForm[AccountingForm[N[CS+PS]],{\[Infinity],2}]];
    Column[{
    StringForm["Først bestemmes ligvægtsmængden og prisen. Dette gøres ved at finde Supply = Demand:"],
    StringForm["Supply = Demand \[DoubleLongRightArrow] Solve[`1` == `2`,Q] = `3`",Supply,Demand,G1],
    StringForm["Q^* = ``",G1],
    StringForm["På samme vis bestemmes den tihørende optimale pris:"],
    StringForm["P^* = Supply(``) = ``",G1,F1],
    StringForm["Nu kan henholdsvis Consumer Surplus, Producer Surplus, og Social Welfare bestemmes:"],
    StringForm["CS = Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^Q^*(Demand)\[DifferentialD]Q - (P^* * Q^*) = Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^`2`(`1`)\[DifferentialD]Q - (`3` * `2`) = `4`",Demand,G1,F1,CS1],
    StringForm["PS = (P^* * Q^*) - Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^Q^*(Supply)\[DifferentialD]Q = (`1` * `2`) - Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^`2`(`3`)\[DifferentialD]Q = `4`",F1,G1,Supply,PS1],
    StringForm["SS = CS + PS = `1` + `2` = `3`",CS1,PS1,SS1],
    Show[(Plot[{Supply,Demand},{Q,0,Slutinterval},
    AxesLabel->{"Q","P"},
    ImageSize->700,
    PlotRange->{{0,Slutx},{0,Sluty}},
    PlotLabels->{"Supply","Demand"," "}]),(Plot[{Supply,Demand,F},{Q,0,G},Filling->2-> F,PlotStyle-> {Orange,Blue,{Thick,Dashed,Black}},
    PlotLabels->Placed[{"CS"},{X1,Y1}]]),(Plot[{Supply,Demand},{Q,0,G},Filling->1-> F,
    PlotLabels->Placed[{"PS"},{X1,Y2}]]),Plot[{Supply,Demand},{Q,0,Slutx}],(ContourPlot[{Q==G},{Q,0,Slutinterval},{y,0,F},ContourStyle-> {Black,Dashed,Thick}]),(ListPlot[{Labeled[{0,F},"P^*"],Labeled[{G,0},"Q^*"],{G,F}},PlotStyle->PointSize[Large]])]},Spacings->1.5],
    Style["Velfærdsteori ved markedsligevægt (FK)",20,Bold],
    Style["Denne funktion beregner ligevægtspris og mængde på et marked under fuldkommen konkurrence. Ydermere beregner og skitserer",12,Plain],
    Style["funktionen Consumer Surplus, Producer Surplus samt Social Surplus. Man skal kende til efterspørgslen og udbuddet på markedet (Demand og Supply).",12,Plain],
    Control@{{Demand,-Q+98},InputField,ImageSize->Full},
    Control@{{Supply,0.5Q+2},InputField,ImageSize->Full},
    TrackedSymbols:>{Demand,Supply}
    ]]
```

I am not able to fix it at all, so I hope that someone here are able to help me. Couldn't see any questions like this.

Also, the label bounding boxes are quiet big sometimes (comparred to the text plotted), and I cant see why this is the case (this also appears above (see the label "P*".

Comment: MadsM, welcome to mma.se. If the following one line captures the essence of  your question, I suggest you replace the  long code in your question with it: `Show[Plot[60-x, {x, 0,60}, Filling->Axis],ListPlot[{Labeled[{10, 30}, "P^*"],    Labeled[{30, 20}, "Q^*"] }, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Background -> None` inside Placed, Labeled and Callout in V12.

```
Show[(Plot[{Supply, Demand}, {Q, 0, Slutinterval}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Q", "P"}, ImageSize -> 700, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, Slutx}, {0, Sluty}}, 
   PlotLabels -> {"Supply", "Demand", " "}]), (Plot[{Supply, Demand, 
    F}, {Q, 0, G}, Filling -> 2 -> F, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue, {Thick, Dashed, Black}}, 
   PlotLabels -> 
    Placed[{"CS"}, {X1, Y1}, Background -> None]]), (Plot[{Supply, 
    Demand}, {Q, 0, G}, Filling -> 1 -> F, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{"PS"}, {X1, Y2}, Background -> None]]), 
 Plot[{Supply, Demand}, {Q, 0, 
   Slutx}], (ContourPlot[{Q == G}, {Q, 0, Slutinterval}, {y, 0, F}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Black, Dashed, 
     Thick}]), (ListPlot[{Labeled[{0, F}, "P^*", Background -> None], 
    Labeled[{G, 0}, "Q^*"], {G, F}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]])]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks this works! however the field placed with text is much bigger than the text itself. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Is this feature documented anywhere?